# How do I select attributes not belonging to a class?

Tags: jquery

How can I select image attribute (src) of img tags that don't belong to a specific class?

Here's the HTML code

```
<div class="content">
    <h1>Welcome to My Homepage</h1>
    <img src="#first">
    <img src="#second">    

    <p class="footer">
        <img src="#1">
        <img src="#2">
        <img src="#3">
    </p>

    <p id='test'> </p>
</div>
```

I have tried both **.not()** and **:not()** selector but I can't seem to make them work. How do I select image source of img tags that don't belong to the "footer" class.

This is what I have tried.

```
<script>
    var url = [];

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.content').filter(function() {
            var data = $(this);
            var image = data.find('img:not(".footer")');

            image.each(function(i,el) {
                url[i] = $(el).attr('src');
                $("#test").text(url);
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why can't you give a `class name` to the `img` outside `.footer`? It is far easy

Comment: Because I am scrapping someone else's website. I can change the HTML elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filter out the images that are child of *footer* class:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").not(".footer > img").each(function() {

    console.log($(this).attr("src"));

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
  <h1>Welcome to My Homepage</h1>
  <img src="#first">
  <img src="#second">
  <p class="footer">
    <img src="#1">
    <img src="#2">
    <img src="#3">
  </p>

  <p id='test'> </p>
```

Comment: Excellent ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**@Developer has a very good solution - I recommend that over this.**

This method implements a filter on the image list - to the same effect. Less optimized though.

```js
var url = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.content').filter(function() {
    var data = $(this);
    var image = data.find('img');
    image.filter( (i, el) => !$(el).parents().hasClass("footer") ).each(function(i, el) {
      console.log($(el).attr("src"));
    })
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="content">
  <h1>Welcome to My Homepage</h1>
  <img src="#first">
  <img src="#second">
  <p class="footer">
    <img src="#1">
    <img src="#2">
    <img src="#3">
  </p>

  <p id='test'> </p>
```